# Using pre_get_posts to edit WooCommerce shop loop affecting ACF options

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Currently on my WooCommerce shop page, all ACF option fields are not coming through, although they come through on other pages. This includes the Logo, a wp_menu footer navigation, and some other advanced custom fields. For reference, see the following screenshots:

The footer on all other pages: ibb.co/4R79mRZ 
The footer on WooCommerce pages(shop): ibb.co/88sjgSd 
The header on all other pages: ibb.co/vwzPs6w 
The header on WooCommerce pages(shop): ibb.co/9NJ0y2v

I have pinpointed the problem to be in my functions.php file, whilst using pre_get_posts to edit the  WooCommerce shop loop based on parameters in the query string.

When I remove this code, the problem goes:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_pre_get_posts' );
function filter_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {
  if(is_shop()){
    if(isset($_GET['brand'])) {
      $filter_term = $_GET['brand'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
      $filter_term = $_GET['cat'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['type'])) {
      $type = $_GET['type'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['priceone'])) {
      $price = $_GET['priceone'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['pricetwo'])) {
      $price = $_GET['pricetwo'];
    }
    if ($filter_term && !$type && !$price) {
      echo "hi";
      $wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
         'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pa_branding',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $filter_term ,
          'include_children' => true,
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $filter_term ,
          'include_children' => true,
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $filter_term , 
          'include_children' => true,
        )
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

Interestingly, when I echo 'hi' within the conditional of this code, the following displays on the front-end: 
Notice the echo'd "hi" in the top left corner: https://ibb.co/3dPg4d9 
Notice the echo'd "hi" in several places in the footer: https://ibb.co/Zfh8rJg

The echoes are showing up in all the places that the site is not pulling through either ACF option fields, or the wp_menu.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the global loop, but I really don't know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `woocommerce_product_query` instead of `pre_get_posts` and see if this helps.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered:

Used woocommerce_product_query instead of pre_get_posts.